# Sculpting problems to attach a head

Tags: mesh, sculpting

I sculpted a character, abd heard and saw it was easier to have a separate shape that makes it easier to manipulate and make two shapes as one mesh. so I had the head separated from the body and tried to attach it as best I can. I joined the meshes, used Clay Strips and and Smooth brushes, but I could not seem to make it look like one mesh. How do i fix this? [image] [image]

Comment: This happens because of normals orientation of vertices which form head and body (note - this does *not* mean solution is to recalculate, it won't help). Sculpting, smoothing etc won't help as technically these are 1 object but 2 meshes

Answer (score 3):

Enable the "bool tools" addon, then use its boolean Union function instead of Join. Then you can go with clay strips and smooth brush (better if dynamic topology is on).

Comment: Does the Bool Tools add-on's Union do anything different from the Boolean modifier?

Comment: I never investigated, but I think they are similar but not identical algorithms.

Comment: I just wondered why you would suggest having to enable an add-on instead of just using the boolean already in blender. Seems simpler.

Comment: You are right, but I suggest only tools in my actual workflow, that I know will deliver the result, and standard boolean modifier is not there, but if you know that it works well I'll be happy to improve and simplify the answer.

Comment: very useful. ty